# Flutter app can't reach user datas in Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm building a flutter app implementing the Firebase Firestore servers. The app lets the user sign up and log in with email and password. The user is synchronized with the AppUser whose datas are stored in a "users" collection. When the home page loads, it prints the user ID. After I sign up a new user, it prints the id. However, when I log in or reload the app, it doesn't print the id (on the console I mean). Down below there are the widget that prints the id, the user provider (I use riverpod), the login and sign up page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:gym/providers/user_provider.dart';
import 'package:gym/widgets/Schede/scheda_widget.dart';

class PersonalWorkouts extends ConsumerWidget {
  const PersonalWorkouts({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final userP = ref.watch(userStateNotifier);

    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
        child: userP.listaSchede.isEmpty
            ? Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Nessuna scheda trovata... Creane una!',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground,
                      ),
                ),
              )
            : ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => SchedaWidget(
                  scheda: userP.listaSchede[index],
                ),
                itemCount: userP.listaSchede.length,
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

user_provider.dart:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:gym/models/scheda_model.dart';
import 'package:gym/models/user_model.dart';

final userStateNotifier =
    StateNotifierProvider<UserState, AppUser>((ref) => UserState());

class UserState extends StateNotifier<AppUser> {
  UserState()
      : super(AppUser(
            email: '',
            userName: '',
            id: '',
            listaSchede: [],
            volumeTot: 0.0,
            volumeSettimanale: [],
            latestWorkouts: [],
            listaPesi: [],
            pesoAttuale: 0.0,
            altezza: 0.0,
            age: 0,
            circBicipiti: 0,
            listaCircBicipiti: [],
            circTricipiti: 0,
            listaCircTricipiti: [],
            circVita: 0,
            listaCircVita: [],
            createdAt: FieldValue.serverTimestamp()));

  void createUser(AppUser newUser) {
    state = newUser;
  }

  String get userId => state.id;

  DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> get documentID =>
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(state.id);

  Future<void> updateUser(AppUser newUser) async {
    DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> documentReference = documentID;

    // Dati da aggiornare
    Map<String, dynamic> dataToUpdate = {
      'listaSchede': newUser.listaSchede,
      'volumeTot': newUser.volumeTot,
      'volumeSettimanale': newUser.volumeSettimanale,
      'latestWorkouts': newUser.latestWorkouts,
      'pesoAttuale': newUser.pesoAttuale,
      'listaPesi': newUser.listaPesi,
      'circBicipiti': newUser.circBicipiti,
      'listaCricBicipiti:': newUser.listaCircBicipiti,
      'circTricipiti': newUser.circTricipiti,
      'listaCircTricipiti': newUser.listaCircTricipiti,
      'circVita': newUser.circVita,
      'listaCircVita': newUser.listaCircVita,
      'altezza': newUser.altezza,
      'age': newUser.age,
      'createdAt': newUser.createdAt
    };

    try {
      await documentReference.update(dataToUpdate);
    } catch (e) {
      print('Errore durante l\'aggiornamento dei dati: $e');
      rethrow;
    }

    state = newUser;
  }

  Future<void> createCollectionForUser(
      AppUser user, String collectionName) async {
    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    try {
      await firestore.collection('users').doc(user.id).set({
        'createdAt': user.createdAt,
        'Età': user.age,
        'Altezza': user.altezza,
        'Peso': user.pesoAttuale
        // Altre proprietà o dati che vuoi associare alla raccolta dell'utente
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('Errore durante la creazione della raccolta: $e');
    }
  }
```

signup page:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:gym/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:gym/providers/user_provider.dart';
import 'package:gym/screens/dashboard.dart';

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
// final FirebaseFirestore _firestore =
//     FirebaseFirestore.instance; // not used

class Informations extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const Informations(
      {super.key,
      required this.enteredEmail,
      required this.enteredPassword,
      required this.enteredUserName});

  final enteredEmail;
  final enteredUserName;
  final enteredPassword;

  @override
  ConsumerState<Informations> createState() {
    return _InformationsState();
  }
}

class _InformationsState extends ConsumerState<Informations> {
  var _enteredPeso;
  var _enteredAltezza;
  var _enteredAge;
  var _isAuthenticating = false;

  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userPnot = ref.watch(userStateNotifier.notifier);

    Future<void> submit(BuildContext context) async {
      final isValid = _form.currentState!.validate();

      if (!isValid) {
        return;
      }

      _form.currentState!.save();

      try {
        setState(() {
          _isAuthenticating = true;
        });
        final userCredentials = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: widget.enteredEmail,
          password: widget.enteredPassword,
        );

        final user = userCredentials.user;
        String userUid = userCredentials.user!.uid;

        // Crea un oggetto User con l'UID dell'utente Firebase
        AppUser newUser = AppUser(
            id: userUid,
            email: userCredentials.user!.email,
            userName: widget.enteredUserName,
            listaSchede: [], // Inizializza listaSchede come vuota
            latestWorkouts: [], // Inizializza latestWorkouts come vuota
            volumeTot: 0.0, // Inizializza volume
            volumeSettimanale: [],
            listaPesi: [],
            pesoAttuale: double.parse(_enteredPeso), // Inizializza peso
            altezza: double.parse(_enteredAltezza), // Inizializza altezza
            age: int.parse(_enteredAge), // Inizializza age
            circBicipiti: 0,
            listaCircBicipiti: [],
            circTricipiti: 0,
            listaCircTricipiti: [],
            circVita: 0,
            listaCircVita: [],
            createdAt: FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

        userPnot.createUser(newUser);

        // Crea un riferimento al documento utente in Firestore utilizzando l'ID dell'utente
        DocumentReference userDocument =
            FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userUid);

        // Salva i campi aggiuntivi nel documento utente
        await userDocument.set(newUser.toMap());

        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const Dashboard(),
        ));

        // await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        //     .collection('users')
        //     .doc(user!.uid)
        //     .set({
        //   'username': widget.enteredUserName,
        //   'email': widget.enteredEmail,
        //   'Età': newUser.age,
        //   'Peso': newUser.pesoAttuale,
        //   'Altezza': newUser.altezza,
        //   //'image_url': imageUrl,
        // });

        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const Dashboard(),
          ),
        );
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
        print(error);
        if (error.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
          //
        }
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).clearSnackBars();
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text(error.message ?? 'Authentication failed'),
          ),
        );
        setState(() {
          _isAuthenticating = false;
        });
      }
    }

    Widget body = Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(
            'Parlaci di te',
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .titleLarge!
                .copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 30),
          Form(
            key: _form,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Età',
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary),
                  ),
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    _enteredAge = value;
                  },
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                TextFormField(
                  keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                      signed: false, decimal: true),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Peso',
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary),
                  ),
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    _enteredPeso = value;
                  },
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                TextFormField(
                  keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                      signed: false, decimal: true),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Altezza',
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary),
                  ),
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    _enteredAltezza = value;
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 15),
          _isAuthenticating
              ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
              : ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    submit(context);
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Salva',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium!.copyWith(
                          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground,
                        ),
                  ),
                ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0), child: body),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

login_screen.dart:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:gym/screens/dashboard.dart';

import 'informations.dart';

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
// final FirebaseFirestore _firestore =
//     FirebaseFirestore.instance; // not used

class LoginScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<LoginScreen> createState() {
    return _LoginScreenState();
  }
}

class _LoginScreenState extends ConsumerState<LoginScreen> {
  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var _isLogin = false;
  String _enteredEmail = '';
  String _enteredUsername = '';
  String _enteredPassword = '';
  bool _isAuthenticating = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void login() {
      final isValid = _form.currentState!.validate();

      if (!isValid) {
        return;
      }

      _form.currentState!.save();

      _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: _enteredEmail,
        password: _enteredPassword,
      );

      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const Dashboard(),
      ));
    }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 30,
                  bottom: 20,
                  left: 20,
                  right: 20,
                ),
                width: 200,
                child: Image.asset('assets/images/dumbell_icon.png'),
              ),
              Card(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary.withOpacity(.7),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                  child: Form(
                    key: _form,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        TextFormField(
                          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Email Address',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          autocorrect: false,
                          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value == null ||
                                value.trim().isEmpty ||
                                !value.contains('@')) {
                              return 'Please enter a valid email address';
                            }

                            return null;
                          },
                          onChanged: (newValue) {
                            _enteredEmail = newValue;
                          },
                        ),
                        if (!_isLogin)
                          TextFormField(
                            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Username',
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            enableSuggestions: false,
                            autocorrect: false,
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value == null ||
                                  value.isEmpty ||
                                  value.trim().length < 4) {
                                return 'Please enter at least 4 characters';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              _enteredUsername = value;
                            },
                          ),
                        TextFormField(
                          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Password',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          obscureText: true,
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value == null || value.trim().length < 6) {
                              return 'Password must be at least 6 characters long';
                            }

                            return null;
                          },
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            _enteredPassword = value;
                          },
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 12),
                        if (_isAuthenticating)
                          const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        if (!_isAuthenticating)
                          ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              _isLogin
                                  ? login()
                                  : Navigator.of(context)
                                      .push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => Informations(
                                        enteredEmail: _enteredEmail,
                                        enteredPassword: _enteredPassword,
                                        enteredUserName: _enteredUsername,
                                      ),
                                    ));
                            },
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: Theme.of(context)
                                  .colorScheme
                                  .secondary
                                  .withOpacity(.8),
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              _isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Signup',
                              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                        if (!_isAuthenticating)
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                _isLogin = !_isLogin;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              _isLogin
                                  ? 'Create an account'
                                  : 'I already have an account',
                              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I also provide the main.dart to ensure I fully initialized the server:

```
Future<void> initializeFirebase() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform, name: 'virtual-gymbro');
}

void main() async {
  await initializeFirebase();

  FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(app: Firebase.app(), persistence: Persistence.LOCAL);

  runApp(ProviderScope(
    child: MaterialApp(
      theme: theme,
      home: const SplashScreen(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    ),
  ));
}
```

Let me know if you have found some solutions.